# Determine the valid arguments by using proofs

Tags: logic

Determine whether these are valid arguments:

a) “If $x^2$ is irrational, then $x$ is irrational. Therefore, if $x$ is irrational, it follows that $x^2$ is irrational.”

b) “If $x^2$ is irrational, then $x$ is irrational. The number $y = \pi^2$ is irrational. Therefore, the number $x = \pi$ is irrational.”

Comment: How do I show the two statements are true or false by using proofs?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it contains multiple questions in one, and as such is unlikely to help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The first is wrong. Consider $x=\sqrt{2}$. The second is OK.

Answer (score 1):

The first is not a valid argument. It is an example of the fallacy of [affirming the consequent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent).

The second is valid. It is an instantiation of the general form of the implication (i.e. the universal statement).

Comment: Actually I stopped before the "therefore" Sorry! :-)

Comment: No worries, @Jean-ClaudeArbaut

Answer (score 0):

Given a statement "if $A$, then $B$":

- its **converse** is "if $B$, then $A$"
- its **inverse** is "if not $A$, then not $B$"
- its **contrapositive** is "if not $B$, then not $A$"

In general, if a statement is true, the only related statement that is *guaranteed* to also be true is the **contrapositive**. (that is, even if a statement is true, its converse and inverse may be false).

In the case of the second statement, you should determine whether the conclusion is a specific instance of the general statement or not.